What are new improvement in Sitecore Cache in 10.4
Can you provide details on the new improvements and enhancements made to Sitecore Cache in version 10.4?
What are impact area ? how it is better to older version?

in the release notes of Sitecore 10.4 you will find some cache improvements:
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/104/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_104/Release_Notes
like :
Performance ​Improved performance of the AccessResultCache class.   551213

Performance Enabled performance improvements for the Translation cache in the default deployment.   560817

Platform    When cache key indexing is enabled, testing a path before creating an item can cause multiple items to be created with the same name.

Platform    The isLanguageFallbackValid cache index size was not calculated correctly. This has been fixed by distinguishing between the size of the cache with and without the index.  600792


Major improvements on the caching that were done are as follows.

Performance of the AccessResultCache was improved. This cache is utilized for caching the user's access rights on an item or a field.

There is a performance improvement on the Translation cache. Make this as true to disable database caches while loading translation items.
This setting is introduced as part of Sitecore 10.4.


Size for the isLanguageFallbackValid cache was not calculated properly. This has been fixed with Sitecore 10.4.
This cache is utilized for language fallback scenario.


You can find more details for the cache improvement made on Sitecore 10.4 Release documentation as below.
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/104/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_104/Release_Notes
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any doubts.
